# Check class property exist when calling from object in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

I'm working on `nodeJs` Here I create `class` and I want that when any property called which is not exist in this class it will print warning in console how can I do this? Maybe using somekind of class function but I'm not able to find anything.

**Class Audio**

```
class User {
 constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
 }
}


// Calling the class 
user = new User('name', 25);
user.height; // This value not exist in class
```

I want to print a warning in console when someone call `height` property which is not exist in class is it possible if yes please let me know.

Comment: I dont think thats possible in vanilla JS. But Typescript solves that problem since adds strict typing

Answer (score 0):

This is no proper way to do it using JavaScript. You can use `hasOwnProperty` method to check it that propery exists.

```
user = new User('name', 25);
if(user.hasOwnProperty('height')){
   user.height; // This value not exist in class
} else {
console.error("Property does not exist on object")
}
```

One more way is you can have a class method to access any property.

```
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  getProperty(name) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return this[name];
    } else {
        console.log(`property ${name} does not exist on object`)
    }
  }
}

// Calling the class 
user = new User('name', 25);
user.getProperty('name') // name
user.getProperty('height'); // This value not exist in class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proxy get handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) to check if the target object has a property:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}


const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (!Reflect.has(target, prop)) {
      console.log(`Property ${String(prop)} does not exist`)
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
}

user = new Proxy(new User('name', 25), handler);

console.log(user.height);
```

Comment: It work but there is little problem when I try to print the hole object it will give error. For example if you console user like `console.log(user)` it will give you error I want to get a result `User { name: 'name', age: 25 }`

Comment: @AzeemHaider You cannot distinguish between a warning and an error. Yes, `console.log` does access non-existing properties, and it's fine.

Comment: @AzeemHaider I believe the error on printing the whole object happens because console log may access env specific symbols. Added `prop` coercion to string in the answer.

Comment: @antonku how can I ignore these extra `props` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Reflect API.

```
Reflect.ownKeys(Reflect.construct(User, []))
```

But User has to have properties defined in the constructor:

```
class User {
  test: string;
  constructor(id: string) {}
```

Will show you the id property but not the test.